# How to script this set of commands?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, export, import

I'd like to get some help with scripting some commands in blender as I would like to automate my workflow.

I have a set of obj file and I would like to generate a script that for each obj file does the following:

1. Import obj file.
2. Create a cube at (0 0 0) with fixed dimensions (0,5 0,5 0,5).
3. Apply boolean difference modifier between the cube and the obj.
4. Triangulate the mesh of the boolean cube.
5. Export only the boolean cube as obj file.

Maybe you cannot provide a complete solution for this scripted workflow but I would appreciate any input or just pointing me in the right direction to learn how to write such a script.

Thank you

Comment: Most, probably all of these steps have been answered  here before.  [Import obj](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+import+obj)  ...  putting it together yourself is IMO the best way to learn.

Comment: The right direction → https://docs.blender.org/api/current/